# Ansible - Prevent playbook executing simultaneously

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that controls a clustered application.  The issue is this playbook can be called/executed a few different ways (manual on the cmd line[multiple SREs working], scheduled task, or programmatically via a 3rd party system).
The problem is if the playbook tries to execute simultaneously, it could cause some issues to the application (nature of the application).

**Question**:

Is there a way to prevent the same playbook from running concurrently on the same Ansible server?

**Environment**:

```
ansible [core 2.11.6]
  config file = /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/playbooks/scoutam_client_configs_playbook/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/etc/ansible/library/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/playbooks/scoutam_client_configs_playbook/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.7 (default, Nov  1 2021, 11:34:21) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lockfile on the controller with the PID of the ansible-playbook process.

```
    - delegate_to: localhost
      vars:
        lockfile: /tmp/thisisalockfile
        my_pid: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cut -d\" \" -f4 /proc/$PPID/stat') }}"
        lock_pid: "{{ lookup('file', lockfile) }}"
      block:
        - name: Lock file
          copy:
            dest: "{{ lockfile }}"
            content: "{{ my_pid }}"
          when: my_lockfile is not exists
            or ('/proc/' ~ lock_pid) is not exists
            or 'ansible-playbook' not in lookup('file', '/proc/' ~ lock_pid ~ '/cmdline')

        - name: Make sure we won the lock
          assert:
            that: lock_pid == my_pid
            fail_msg: "{{ lockfile }} is locked by process {{ lock_pid }}"
```

Finding the current PID is the trickiest part; `$PPID` in the lookup is still the PID of a child, so we're grabbing the grandparent out of `/proc/`

Comment: Let me play with that.  I did not think about going to PROC for my PID.  If that can work reliably, I much prefer the simpler code and remove the race-condition.  Will report back later.  tx

Comment: This is a much simpler and better solution.  Tx

Comment: The `is not exists` are straightforward; the `exists` test checks if a path exists on the Ansible controller (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths). The last part is a (mostly unnecessary) check that the PID hasn't been reused by another process. This is unlikely to happen, especially when pid_max is higher than the historical 32768, but I have had unlikelier things happen.

Answer (score 1):

you could test if file exist at the start of playbook and stop the play if the file exist with meta, if not you create the file to block another launch:

```
- name: lock_test
  hosts: all
  vars:
    lock_file_path: /tmp/ansible-playbook.lock      
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Check if some file exists
      delegate_to: localhost
      stat:
        path: "{{ lock_file_path }}"
      register: lock_file 

    - block:
        - name: "end play "
          debug:
            msg: "playbook already launched, ending play"

        - meta: end_play
      when: lock_file.stat.exists

    - name: create lock_file {{ lock_file_path }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      file: 
        path: "{{ lock_file_path }}"
        state: touch

  # ****************** tasks start
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "something to do"
  # ****************** tasks end

  post_tasks:
    - name: delete the lock file  {{ lock_file_path }}
      delegate_to: localhost
      file: 
        path: "{{ lock_file_path }}"
        state: absent
```

but you have to have **only one playbook in your play**  even the first playbook stops, the second is launched except if you do the same test in the next playbook.

it exist a little lapse time before test and creation of file... so the probality to launch twice the same playbook in same second is very low.

The solution will be always better than you have actually

Another solution is to lock an existing file, and test if file is locked or not, but be careful with this option.. see lock, flock in unix command

Comment: I had seen some similar solutions but as this is going into a production app, I cannot have the race condition of a legacy lock file being left around due to a abandoned or failed run.  This means someone would have to manually clean up the legacy lock file before that Ansible server could run that playbook again.
So I am trying similar approach but trying to associate the lock file with the initial (master) PID (not the forked PID) somehow.
This is being a very complicated to accomplish, so far.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this here but do not consider it a final/perfect answer.
it does work for general purposes.

I put this 'playbook_lock.yml' at the root of my playbook and call it in before any roles.

playbook_lock.yml:

```yaml
# ./playbook_lock.yml
#
## NOTES:
## - Uses '/tmp/' on Ansible server as lock file directory
## - Format of lock file: E.g. 129416_20211103094638_playbook_common_01.lock
## -- Detailed explanation further down
## - Race-condition:
## -- Assumption playbooks will not run within 10sec of each other
## -- Assumption lockfiles were not deleted within 10sec
## -- If running the playbook manually with manual input of Ansible Vault
## --- Enter creds within 10 sec or the playbook will consider this run legacy
## - Built logic to only use ansbile.builin modules to not add additional requirements
##
#
---
  ## Build a transaction ID from year/month/day/hour/min/sec
- name: debug_transactionID
  debug:
    msg: "{{ transactionID }}"
  vars:
    filter: "{{ ansible_date_time }}"
    transactionID: "{{ filter.year + filter.month + filter.day + filter.hour + filter.minute + filter.second }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: reg_transactionID

  ## Find current playbook PID
  ## Race-condition => assumption playbooks will not run within 10sec of each other
  ## If playbook is already running >10secs, this return will be empty
- name: debug_current_playbook_pid
  ansible.builtin.shell:
      ## serach PS for any command matching the name of the playbook | remove the 'grep' result | return only the 1st one (if etime < 10sec)
    cmd: "ps -e -o 'pid,etimes,cmd' | grep {{ ansible_play_name }} | grep -v grep | awk 'NR==1{if($2<10) print $1}'"
  changed_when: false
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: reg_current_playbook_pid

  ## Check for existing lock files
- name: find_existing_lock_files
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: /tmp
    patterns: "*_{{ ansible_play_name }}.lock"
    age: 1s
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: reg_existing_lock_files

  ## Check and verify existing lock files
- name: block_discovered_existing_lock_files
  block:
      ## build fact of all lock files discovered
    - name: fact_existing_lock_files
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_existing_lock_files: "{{ fact_existing_lock_files | default([]) + [item.path] }}"
      loop: "{{ reg_existing_lock_files.files }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      when:
        - reg_existing_lock_files.matched > 0

      ## Build fact of all discovered lock files
    - name: fact_playbook_lock_file_dict
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_playbook_lock_file_dict: "{{ fact_playbook_lock_file_dict | default([]) + [data] }}"
      vars:
          ## E.g. lockfile => 129416_20211103094638_playbook_common_01.lock 
        var_pid: "{{ item.split('/')[2].split('_')[0] }}" ## extract the 1st portion = PID
        var_transid: "{{ item.split('/')[2].split('_')[1] }}" ## extract 2nd portion = TransactionID
        var_playbook: "{{ item.split('/')[2].split('_')[2:] | join('_') }}" ## Extract the remaining and join back together = playbook file
        data:
          {pid: "{{ var_pid }}", transid: "{{ var_transid }}", playbook: "{{ var_playbook }}"}
      loop: "{{ fact_existing_lock_files }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

      ## Check each discovered lock file
      ## Verify the PID is still operational
    - name: shell_verify_pid_is_active
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: "ps -p {{ item.pid }} | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'"
      loop: "{{ fact_playbook_lock_file_dict }}"
      changed_when: false
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: reg_verify_pid_is_active

      ## Build fact of discovered previous playbook PIDs
    - name: fact_previous_playbook_pids
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_previous_playbook_pids: "{{ fact_previous_playbook_pids | default([]) + [item.stdout | int] }}"
      loop: "{{ reg_verify_pid_is_active.results }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

      ## Build fact is playbook already operational
      ## Add PIDs together
      ## If SUM =0 => No PIDs found (no previous playbooks running)
      ## If SUM != 0 => previous playbook is still operational
    - name: fact_previous_playbook_operational
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_previous_playbook_operational: "{{ ((fact_previous_playbook_pids | sum) | int) != 0 }}"
  
  when:
    - reg_existing_lock_files.matched > 0
    - reg_current_playbook_pid.stdout is defined

  ## Continue with playbook, as no previous instances running
- name: block_continue_playbook_operations
  block:
      ## Cleanup legacy lock files, as the PIDs are not operational
    - name: stat_cleanup_legacy_lock_files
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ fact_existing_lock_files }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: fact_existing_lock_files | length >= 1
    
      ## Create lock file for current playbook
    - name: stat_create_playbook_lock_file
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ var_playbook_lock_file }}"
        state: touch
        mode: '0644'
      vars:
        var_playbook_lock_file: "{{ reg_current_playbook_pid.stdout }}_{{ reg_transactionID.msg }}_{{ ansible_play_name }}.lock"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
  
  when:
    - reg_current_playbook_pid.stdout is defined

  ## Fail & exit playbook, as previous playbook is still operational
- name: block_playbook_already_operational
  block:
    - name: fail
      fail:
        msg: 'Playbook "{{ ansible_play_name }}" is already operational!  This playbook will now exit without any modifications!!!'
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
  
  when: (fact_previous_playbook_operational is true) or
        (reg_current_playbook_pid.stdout is not defined)


...
```

Comment: dont forget to close the question by upvoting or / andvalidating your or my answer